# Object not getting picked from second level cache in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

i specified the below  properties in cfg file.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
     net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

In my main1 program i create the person with id 1  and commited and made that thread on hold after commit. Then i start the another thread T2 which is getting ther person with id 1 with below code

```
person = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);
```

when T2 passed above statement, it generate the below query in background

```
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id0_1_, person0_.cname as cname0_1_ from     MyProject1.Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
```

**I am not sure why thread T2 reading from database instead of getting it from second level cache? as i am using usage as  read-write**

My Mapping looks like

```
<class name="com.daasl.Person"    >
<cache usage="read-write"/> 
  <id name="id" type="int">
     <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="name" column="cname" type="string"/>
 </class>
```

Comment: Did you [enabled](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e2196) cache on `Person` entity? Is your entity `Serializable`? Have you configured `ehcache.xml` properly?

Comment: Hi Tomsaz,Answers are here -Did you enabled cache on Person entity? -As you can see the person mapping  with <cache usage="read-write"/> .Is your entity Serializable?- Yes.  Have you configured ehcache.xml properly?-As i said in begining of post  that i configured both the properties i.e hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache and hibernate.cache.provider_class in hibernate.cfg.xml. Is there any thing else we need to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue.Actually each main programm has its own jvm instance, hence its own session factory.So second level cache wont work here. I tried the same thing in the same main programe once session is closed after creating the person in it. Then open new session and tried to get the same person, it got it from second level cache.